# StackOverflowError for Android Pre-Launch Test with Google Maps Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps-flutter, prelaunch

While I have not had any issues with Android Studio and either iOS simulator or Android emulators in debug build. I have now tried to upload the release build app to **pre-launch with Google Play Console** and I can't figure out why I can't run a test without crashes.

I have tried many upgrades/downgrades, but it crashes on the maps only, no other screen. Even the sample example of **google_maps_flutter** with the basic configuration when creating a new flutter project crashes.

I do not have an android device to test so I'm limited to Internal Testing. No problems with an iPhone which works just fine.

This report was from the following device on Google Testing in the Google Play Console, this happens on each test iteration build:

- Device: Samsung Galaxy S9
- Screen Size: 1080x2009
- Screen density (DPI): 480
- OpenGL ES version: 3.2
- CPU: Qualcomm SDM845
- Android Version (SDK): Android 8.0 (SDK 26)
- RAM (total memory): 3,584 MB
- ABI: ARM64_V8 Locale: en_US

**Here's the stack trace report:**

```
Process: androidx.test.tools.crawler.stubapp, PID: 7201
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
    at android.util.LongArray.clone(LongArray.java:117)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.init(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3259)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.obtain(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3051)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityCache.getNode(AccessibilityCache.java:231)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityInteractionClient.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityId(AccessibilityInteractionClient.java:287)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getChild(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:995)
    at android.support.test.uiautomator.e.f(ByMatcher.java:7)
    at android.support.test.uiautomator.e.f(ByMatcher.java:10) **repeats 122 times **
```

Here's the flutter doctor -v

```
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/Company/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (6 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Company/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

 
[✓] Connected device (1 available)            
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

[google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Comment: Same issue, although I have tested in a physical device as well. (Not using google maps flutter)

Comment: I have the same crash report on production... I'm also not using google maps as @GibreelAbdullah

Comment: Same here. And I can't promote my internal release to alpha release. I suppose it's block from play store because of these errors. Any solution ?

Comment: Same here, java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1041KB exception. please share if you have found the solution.

Comment: same error java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1041KB at Android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.init(AccessibilityNodeInfo

Answer (score 1):

This was also posted on flutter's GitHub which got an answer. I'm simply ignoring the pre-launch test report errors with these types of errors.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74902